# Merging 2 mysql rds into one

Tags: mysql, replication, amazon-rds

Is it possible to merge 2 MySQL rds into one with no downtime ? They both don’t have any overlapping databases

I am thinking of loading the databases from one of the databases into the other via mysql dump then replicate from the other rds to catch up, then failover

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might give you very close to zero downtime.

I'm assuming you have two instances (A and B) without any replication.  And you want to move the data from B to A.  I'll use the notation B-->A.

1. Turn on `log_bin` on B.
2. Capture a mysqldump of B, and make sure it includes the binlog position (or GTID).  Do not dump any system tables or other tables that might conflict with A.
3. Load the dump into A.
4. Enable replication and make sure it starts at the saved position.
5. Check that A looks OK.
6. When the load is finished, redirect clients from B to A.  (This is the only downtime, and it is very brief.)  (This is the "failover" for the B clients.)

If, instead, you want to create C with copies of D and E:

0. Make sure the MySQL version handles "multi-source replication".
1. Create an empty instance C.
2. As above D-->C; excluding the failover for D clients.
3. As above E-->C; excluding the failover for E clients.
4. Double-check that C looks good after both sets of data are moved into place.  And check that replication is keeping the data up to date.
5. Failover all the clients (from D and E to C).

I am suggesting the above based on regular MySQL or MariaDB.  I do not know if there are any gotchas in the RDS version.

Comment: Rds doesn’t support multi source replication. Could I simply load up 2 with both dumps then replicate one source then failover then the next?

Comment: @ChrisMuench - Yes, something like that.  Be sure to avoid the "mysql" database; it contains GRANTs, etc.